# Linking Excel tables with multiple similar fields

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there a way to link (or vlookup) two Excel data sheets having mutliple duplicate fields? For example, I want to join session and person data as described below (sample with dummy data):

[image]

Both sheets have thousands of rows.

The output should be somthing like that, e.g. for person 00001:

[image]

Comment: What output do you want? There are tools to do the join such as VBA SQL  and powerquery and possibly range consolidation with pivottable wizard. But you do want a unique identifier and your Person ID at first glance seems a little confusing as has multiple tel numbers for 00001 and 2 of the Person IDs havbe multiple sessions so how you want the output to look is important.

Comment: https://www.powerquery.training/portfolio/merge-tables/

Comment: @QHarr: edited my question, added a screen shot about the output. A user may have multiple phone numbers and can have multiple sessions. Any ideas on ho to re-arraneg the data are also welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Excel PowerQuery did the trick.